# Are Intent data saved across activity restart?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

We usually start an activity passing various parameters in the `Intent`.
If the activity is created e.g. after being inactive/background for a while, can I count on the `Intent` always having the parameters that were originally passed to start the activity?
Or would I have to save them in the `Bundle` in the `onSaveInstanceState` function?

Comment: you could probably test this yourself, to an extent, although i do understanding wanting a definite answer here

Comment: @a_local_nobody: If I test I would test the behavior on a specific device essentially. I was interested if this is actually documented somewhere that guarantees it for all devices

Comment: yeah i understand. only way i would "test" this, would be to have an activity, change the language on the phone and see if it app then still works like it should when you get back to it. changing language will probably count as a configuration change in which case you might get an idea if this works or doesnt, but i understand the need for wanting an actual documented answer